# How to grep for Session ABUSE count in ISS logs

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have extracted the following ISS logs into export.txt and I would like to find out which sessions could be abusing their access and looking at other ids information on the server.

export.txt

```
session=12345 id=1
session=12345 id=1
session=12345 id=1
session=12346 id=2
session=12346 id=2
session=12346 id=2
session=12347 id=3
session=12347 id=3
session=12347 id=4
session=12347 id=5
session=12347 id=6
session=12347 id=7
session=12348 id=4
session=12348 id=4
session=12348 id=4
session=12348 id=4
session=12349 id=5
session=12349 id=6
session=12349 id=1
session=12349 id=2
session=12349 id=3
session=12350 id=6
session=12350 id=6
```

I am looking for a way to grep/awk/sed (any of these commands)
to show me sessions that have more that one unique id

Example:

```
5  12347
4  12349
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe your log to:

```
sort | uniq | sed -r 's/session=([0-9]+).*/\1/' | uniq -c | grep -v '^[ ]*1 '
```

Use `-E` instead `-r` on BSD-like (like OSX).

Comment: @secghost You can also `sort export.txt | uniq ...`